# Views exposed form taxonomy translation

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, search

On a website we use taxonomy translation (Drupal 7), it's working fine on all exposed forms from Views. But on one exposed form (the Search form) it isn't working. Inside the views configuration (Filter criteria) it shows (indexed) next to the taxonomy term that isn't translated.

I found a lot of results about taxonomy translation on Drupal Answers / Google, but the taxonomy translation IS working, but not for indexed items.